# How to merge two directories in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, files

I have two folders `/var/first/app` and `/var/second/app`. I have different files within both folders and few are same. I want to merge `/var/second/app` to `/var/first/app`. How can I do that?

Comment: copy them recursively with `cp -rf` (it'll overwrite the target files) then remove the older directory files.

Comment: Do you have same files within the same folders?

Comment: @Ravexina: yes, if they are same then in similar folder structure

Comment: To get good answers, you will need to be specific about exactly what you want to happen for the "few are same"

Comment: What do you mean "merge"? What exactly do you want to happen to files that appear in both directories with identical names?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
rsync -av /var/second/app /var/first/app
```

Comment: I had to use `rsync -av /app/. app/.` or the app directory would exist inside the first/app. As so `/var/first/app/app`. Perhaps because the path was not fully qualified.

Answer (score 7):

Use something like:

```
cp -r /var/first/app /var/second/
rm -r /var/first/app
```

or change `cp -r` to `cp -a`  to preserve ownership and timestamps.

You can also use `-i` to make sure what is going on. it's going to prompt you before overwriting anything.

Comment: cp -ri first/* second

Answer (score 0):

You may first backup your destination folder (just in case) :

```
cp -r /var/first/app /var/first/app.backup
```

If you don't care overwriting files :

```
cp -fr /var/second/app /var/first/app
```

It will copy recursively the second folder into the first one, overwriting files with same names.

If you don't want to overwrite existing files :

```
cp -nr /var/second/app /var/first/app
```

If all is ok, you can remove the backup :

```
rm -rf /var/first/app.backup
```

Comment: cp -ri  dir1/*  dir2/